# Using Twilio For East Africa - Kenya, Tanzania, Malawi

Tags: django, twilio, sms-gateway

We have now created a beta GIS platform (PostgreSQL, Django, Leaflet) that also enables users to send SMS messages to a Twilio number, which are then viewed within the app and then annotated by admins to reports.

The aim of these crowd-sourced reports is to empower local communities in rural East Africa with a voice to share incidents relating to water pollution and sanitation. We will be showcasing the web GIS platform to the wider international community (who have come together in East Africa to deal with this issue - known as the 'maji programme').

To cut it short, we are using Twilio to receive SMS messages and currently only have a UK mobile number joined to the account. In order to conduct a field trial, it is very, very important that we can enable citizens to report and send SMS messages to a more local mobile number, namely Kenya and Tanzania, with Malawi soon to follow.

Having recently seen that Twilio has added support for Kenya, we are looking to see how Tanzania and Malawi might be addressed.  Is it a case that we wait for Twilio to roll out support in these countries (already sent them that question) or is there a way to bootstrap this situation?

**The only requirement that really matters is that citizens are able to text a local mobile phone, which in turn is input into our django app.**

I would very much value your collective input...whether that be a method to bootstrap around the current Twilio issue, or indeed alternative ways to address local Tanzanian and Malawian needs.

Answer (score 2):

As it's not possible yet to get a local number from Twilio, you could use another local SMS solution say [SMSLeopard](https://smsleopard.com/) or [Uwazi](http://www.uwaziimobile.com/). Uwazi have an API but I haven't taken it for a test drive while SMSleopard currently only works with a spreadsheet. You could collect the texts to a spreadsheet and then develop a custom solution to send the data to a database or to Twilio. The best solution so far for your case I think is [AfricasTalking](https://www.africastalking.com/). They cover Kenya, Tanzania, Uganda, Rwanda, Malawi and Nigeria

**Update**
Twilio have provisioned new local numbers as of June 2017

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: django-two-factor-auth is here for illustration purposes, it interfaces wit the Twilio gateway and uses the Twilio package, so I think it is a good example for implementing multi-gateway SMS systems.

I recently wrote a multi SMS gateway solution that supports different backends in the style of [django-two-factor-auth](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth) SMS GW. We primarily use it to send authentication tokens, but the principle is the same; You probably want to send messages through multiple different SMS providers.

You should probably look into the style introduced in there and provide

- SMS APIs that can be called through in an uniform way to SEND messages
- SMS return URLs for receiving SMS messages that similarly provide different endpoints for different providers but interface similarly.

This would mean that you would have some gateway similar to the [Twilio gateway](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/blob/master/two_factor/gateways/twilio/gateway.py) introduced in django-two-factor-auth with dedicated return URLs and a different gateway and different return URLs for a different provider:

```
class SMSLeopardGateway(object):
    """ 
    A Gateway for sending and receiving SMS messages. 
    Sending just sends a HTTP message, return provides
    a callback URL that interfaces to the receive_sms method.
    """

    def send_sms(self, device, message):
        # handle sending messages through an uniform API

    @staticmethod
    def receive_sms(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Django request interface for receiving messages

urlpatterns = [
    url(^'/sms/receive/leopard', SMSLeopardGateway.receive_sms),
]
```

This way you could build a lean support for multiple different gateways and just find out where your numbers are located and react to that in your code; you could provide just one SMS callback URL as well and just interface that to different backends.

The Twilio gateway and django-two-factor-auth source code is not that complicated to read through and you could find a lot of inspiration from there.